# Android BOOT_COMPLETED not working!

Tags: android, htc-hero

This is a simple program i created to test BOOT_COMPLETED event of Android but it's not working! am i doing something wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.enea.training.bootdemo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".BootDemoReceiver">
            <Intent-filter>
                <action android:name ="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </Intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

java:

```
public class BootDemoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final String TAG = "BootDemoReceiver";

     @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent bootintent) {
         Log.v(TAG, "Come on");
     }
}
```

Comment: Just added the 'java' string. not really neccessary for content, but now the 2 codes are split, and the system can recognize it's java, and add the pretty colors ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it matters, but try changing `<Intent-filter>` to `<intent-filter>` (note lowercase 'i').

Comment: yep worked. thanks a lot. i spent almost whole day trying to figure out what was wrong!